# What was the motive for trying to destroy Andy's relationship with Becky?

Tags: detectorists

In series 1 episode 4 of *Detectorists*, a compromising photograph of Andy and Sophie is anonymously left at Becky's. In the following episode it is revealed that this photo was taken by Paul of the *Antiquisearchers*.

What was the motive for giving the compromising photograph to Becky? It is difficult to see how the rivalry between the *Antiquisearchers* and the *DMDC* justifies or merits such a vindictive action.

Comment: I mean, that's kind of the point.  Some of the humour of the show derives from the quaint rivalry between the detectorist groups.  The show is filled with people taking the activity far too seriously.